# Visual Studio 2015 + Windows 10 Deployment

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, deployment, visual-studio-2015

So I'm new in the Visual Studio 2015 (Community), I liked the C# + XAML set so I start learning from scratch (I'm a VB6,Php,Js Dev) and I found the following issues.

a) How do yo do a standalone installation or release of a simple application?. (When I build the release it says: this application can only run in the context of an app container).

b) By programming on this set (c# + XAML), can I build applications for WinXP,Win7,Win8? (I found that the only requirement is to have .NET 4 installed, and when creating the solution on vs2015 target that framework).

I'm used to the fact that I can build my app and it will run just by installing the dlls on the client machine.

Thanks in advance for any answer or directions to solve this questions.

Comment: please create two questions, it makes it easier to give a complete answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if you have created a Modern app project. That will only run on Win8 and later.

If you want to use C# along with XAML, you should re-create the project as a WPF Application. When you create a new project, you would just look under the "Windows" section. Do not select "Universal" or "Windows 8" unless you intend to build for newer systems. WPF projects can be run on WinXP and later. I believe WPF also has a minimum requirement of .NET 3.0.